# Get Request for RESTful service not working

Tags: html, node.js

I'm trying to use a restful service to access data that is posted to a MongoDB cluster. My problem is that I can't even connect to the service, the get request doesn't seem to be working. Console.log("test")is not reached and I'm met with a blank console, so I don't think the readystate is changing.

I've done a ton of troubleshooting and found that the link works on its own (https://RESTfulServiceExample.[REPL.IT USERNAME].repl.co/items) and displays the data when pasted into the search bar. I've also tried changing browsers and even compared to my friend's code which works and STILL I can't even seem to connect.

I'm sure it's just some dumb little mistake but I'm completely at a loss here so any help is MUCH appreciated!

File with get request. I edited out the username. 'item' is the name of the MongoDB cluster.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  console.log("test"); //NOT REACHED
  var responseObj = JSON.parse
  (xhttp.responseText); 

};
}
//PROBLEM HERE
xhttp.open("GET", "https://RESTfulServiceExample.[REPL.IT USERNAME].repl.co/items", true);
xhttp.send();



</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"> 
</script></head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

RESTful Service:

Index.js: (edited out username and password of mongodb.

```
var express = require('express'); // control-shift-S to bring up shell in repl.it and npm 
install express / other packages
var app = express();
var port = 5000; // the port is automatically routed by the repl.it domain

mongoose = require('mongoose');
Item = require('./model/model.js');
bodyParser = require('body-parser');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise; // for asynchronous callbacks
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://[USERNAME]:[PASSWORD]@cluster0.thmkp.mongodb.net/Pokemon? 
retryWrites=true&w=majority'); 

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var routes = require('./routes/routes'); //importing route
routes(app); //register the route


app.listen(port);
```

Routes.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(app) {
  var itemList = require('../controllers/controller');

app.route('/items')
  .get(itemList.list_items)
  .post(itemList.create_item); 

app.route('/items/:id')
  .get(itemList.get_item)
  .put(itemList.update_item) 
  .delete(itemList.delete_item);
};
```

Comment: The index.js file isn't really important, instead you should show the routes file where the request is handled. Also there are some events fired for the xmlhttprequest, it might show possibe error, progress etc. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress

Comment: @Molda Thank you. Edited to include routes file.

Comment: Well Routes.js isn't really helping either as it doesn't contain the handler function(controller) which is the important part. It seems it is in controllers `itemList.list_items`.

Comment: To see all the requests comming in to your server you can add simple middleware like so `app.use(function(req, res, next){ console.log(req.method, req.url); next();})` just bellow `app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Comment: @Molda Thanks for that. Found out that the server IS getting the GET call. Also found out that 'this.status' is staying at 0, which is probably why the console.log isn't being reached. No idea why that is though.

Comment: have you tried xhttp.status instead of this.status?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
// your code block
}
```